# Knockout.js how do i bind to a sub property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I know how to bind to a property, but how do i bind to a property like:
Parent.Child

Using the hello world example on Knockout JS.com:
Html:

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
<h2>ChildProperty: <span data-bind="text: parentProperty.childProperty"> </span>!</h2>
```

Javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
this.lastName = ko.observable(last);
this.parentProperty = ko.observable(
    {
        childProperty: "I am a child Property"
    });

this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName      and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"));
```

I would like to create a binding to the childProperty.

I created a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/szk2e/1/)

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So so very close!

You want

```
<span data-bind="text: parentProperty().childProperty"> </span>
```

Your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/szk2e/2/

Comment: Thank you Tim! How did I not think to try this

Comment: This answer helped me on a loosely related problem.  Thanks!

Comment: ahh! where is this in the knockout docs btw? I couldn't see it

Comment: I suppose you could glean it from this [http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html] where you realize it must be evaluating `price() > 50 ? 'expensive' : 'affordable'` and then realize that `price().subProperty` would work

Comment: @Sinaesthetic If you post your code, we could help you. Do you have a link to jsbin or jsfiddle with your code example?

Comment: facepalm moment. ty

Answer (score 18):

Adding an answer here as this is the best fit to my particular situation...

There is a situation where Tim's answer won't work.  This is when the parent property can be `undefined`.

For example, if you're using the common pattern of *itemsSource* and *selectedItem* (where the user selects a single item from a list) *selectedItem* will be **undefined** on first evaluation, and whenever the user has undone their selection.  Using the binding `text:selectedItem().SomeProperty` will "break" knockout, preventing bindings from being evaluated.  Note, trying to short circuit this using the `visible` binding (e.g., `text:selectedItem().SomeProperty, visible:selectedItem`) will NOT work.

In this case, you have to use **the `with` binding** to switch the binding context to the value of the property.  So, using OP's example...

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
<h2 data-bind="with:parentProperty">ChildProperty: 
    <span data-bind="text: childProperty"></span>!
</h2>
```

Note that the behavior for this binding is (from the docs)

> The with binding will dynamically add or remove descendant elements depending on whether the associated value is null/undefined or not

If you also need to hide the container depending on whether the property is undefined or not, then you should use the `<!-- ko -->` virtual element to surround the container.  [More information can be found here.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this answer. I've been looking a way to solve this for a while. Thanks!!!

Comment: As others have mentioned, I think this is the better answer, but nevertheless THANK YOU. This exact scenario was wrecking me for a good half hour.