# Issue with KnockoutJS mapping child property

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I am just beginning to learn KnockoutJS so I am probably missing something simple but here is my issue.

Below is my ClassType class

```
public class ClassType
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Class Slots")]
    public int ClassSlots { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method in my controller to return a list of all the types set up called GetAll

```
public JsonResult GetAll()
    {
        var classtypes = classtypeRepository.All;
        return Json(classtypes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my view I have the following code to load the data into my viewmodel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("/ClassTypes/GetAll/", "", function (data) {
        var viewModel = {
            classtypes: ko.observableArray()
        };
        viewModel.classtypes = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
});
</script>
```

I have thrown the following div into my view to make sure something is returned

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></div>
```

The following is returned

```
{"classtypes":[{"ID":1,"Description":"Online","ClassSlots":30},{"ID":2,"Description":"In-House","ClassSlots":15},{"ID":3,"Description":"Hands-On","ClassSlots":10}]}
```

If I try to bind anything to the view model it does not seem to understand the properties

```
 <tbody>
    <!-- ko.foreach: classtypes -->
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Description">
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: ClassSlots">
            </td>
        </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

I used the knockoutJS mapping plugin to bring the data in which I thought would create the structure of the viewmodel for me.  What am I missing?

Comment: Please try to do the following: `<td data-bind="text: $data.Description">`

Comment: that did not work for me.  I get the same results

Comment: OK I found a solution but maybe someone can tell em why this worked.  I am using knockout 2.2.0 which i thought supported control flow templates but that seems to be the problem.  If I take otu the comments and on the tbody tag put <tbody data-bind="foreach: classtypes"> the data shows up

Comment: I've updated my answer which should answer your last question regarding foreach comment

Comment: If you've ended up here because your parent property is undefined, breaking your bindings, [see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091530#25612303) (sorry for the notification, OP!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct except one thing. 
To get the specific property from Array you should call `$data.YOUR_SPECIFIC_PROPERTY_NAME`

**HTML CODE:**

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #222;">
  <tr data-bind="foreach: classtypes">
    <td></td>
    <td data-bind="text: $data.Description"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: $data.ClassSlots"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript CODE**

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.classtypes = ko.observableArray(initialData);
};

var initialData = [{"ID":1,"Description":"Online","ClassSlots":30},
                   {"ID":2,"Description":"In-House","ClassSlots":15},
                   {"ID":3,"Description":"Hands-On","ClassSlots":10}];

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(initialData));
```

Also I've created jsFiddle for you **[Click here to see the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/9aSqc/)**

**START UPDATE**
Also it works with foreach comments, but you've one typo in `ko.foreach` comment, actually you should change a dot ('.') to empty space (' ') like this `<!-- ko foreach -->` , also here will be your correct HTML Code:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #222;">
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: classtypes -->
    <tr >
      <td></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.Description"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.ClassSlots"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  <tbody>
</table>
```

**END UPDATE**

Comment: your answer is correct as far as using the foreach on the body tag.  I do not see what you are doing differently in the last bit of HTML that is different from what I did with comments to make it work though.  Could you highlight the differences for me.

Comment: Oh, sure, forgot to mention:)  your foreach comment has some extra point `ko.foreach` but between `ko` and `foreach` should be a space `ko foreach`

Comment: Fixing the `foreach` syntax is enough, the `$data` prefix is not necessary